# Which is the correct address format?

Tags: correspondance, formatage

I am working on french addresses... which one is correct:

```
LA POSTE DIRECTION DU COURRIER
M MICHEL DUPONT SERVICE ACHATS
CITE DESCARTES
2 BOULEVARD NEWTON
CHAMPS SUR MARNE
77453 MARNE LA VALLEE CEDEX 2
```

OR

```
LA POSTE DIRECTION DU COURRIER
SERVICE ACHATS
M MICHEL DUPONT
CITE DESCARTES
2 BOULEVARD NEWTON
CHAMPS SUR MARNE
77453 MARNE LA VALLEE CEDEX 2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will reach their recipients.

I would avoid the "all caps" style except for the last two lines, add a dot after M and use accents where needed.

> La Poste - Direction du Courrier
>   Service Achats - M. Michel Dupont
>   Cité Descartes
>   2 boulevard Newton
>   CHAMPS SUR MARNE
>   77453 MARNE LA VALLEE CEDEX 2

Comment: Useful information on the [French Wikipedia.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adresse_postale)

Comment: @Feelew Thanks for the link, I knew about the all caps recommendation for the last two lines but forgot about the no accent one for them.